# Jenkins email could not connect failure

Tags: jenkins, smtp

I have tried with various SMTP servers but I cannot get Jenkins to send an email. I get the `could not connect` error - nothing else, just this error.

See the screenshot below.

Any ideas why? I am using the Jenkins docker container, firewall is off.

I do not have an email server running inside the Jenkins container. I figure I don't need one if Gmail is going to send the email for me.

[image: Image of stack trace from SMTP handler in Jenkins UI]

Comment: Can you telnet to your smtp server on the appropriate port?

Comment: i tried ... telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 ... but nothing it just hangs ... im not sure what response i am expecting, but getting none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gmail configuration looks correct. Usually these issues come down to a firewall, but if you are sure that is not the problem it could be your Gmail account settings.

An additional configuration is required in the Gmail account from which the mail is being triggered. This step authorizes apps like Jenkins to use the Gmail account.

[Gmail - Allowing less secure apps to access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

After performing this step emails should be triggered successfully.

Comment: It would be better to use TLS when possible, rather than reduce the security of the account

Answer (score 1):

UNBELIEVABLE. 2 days later. Fixed.

I found that my Cloud computing provider (Scaleway) disable outgoing SMTP by default and I had to enable SMTP via their web interface. [Details here](https://www.scaleway.com/faq/server/network/#-I-cannot-send-any-email).

These commands helped me to determine that outgoing SMTP was in fact as dead as a donut:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465

openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls smtp

echo "Hello world" | swaks -4 --server smtp.gmail.com:587 --from user@gmail.com --to user@example.net -tls --tls-protocol sslv3 --auth PLAIN --auth-user user@gmail.com --auth-password 7654321 --h-Subject "Test message" --body -
```